# What to change in AndroidManifest to make app compatible with S8, S8+?

Tags: android

I thought it would be able to be downloaded on those devices because I have xxxhdpi/large set?

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all phones -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"  android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="560"     android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="560"     android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"  android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- all tablets -->
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi"   android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"  android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi"   android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"  android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>
```

It says my app is supported on the S8 (also, why does it say 1080 x 1920? That's not one of the 3 resolutions you can choose on the S8):
[image]

But for the S8+ it says my app is not supported[image]

However, my app can't be downloaded on EITHER phone. So I'm not sure why it says the S8 is supported.

Comment: if you want to be be compatible with all phones and tablets - remove the `<compatible-screens>` tag all together

Comment: I don't want to do that though. I want to keep the current     <compatible-screens> but just add S8/S8+ to it.

Comment: the comments say all that you want to support all phones and tablets though?

Comment: I want to know why my app is not able to be downloaded on the S8/S8+ through the Play Store if I have `<screen android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" android:screenSize="large" />` set. Isn't that the correct screen density and screen size for those phones?

Comment: Same problem. I put dpi directly <screen android:screenDensity="420" android:screenSize="normal"/>, but still doesn't show compatible. @Dan Any luck?

Comment: Nope. I still haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem.. this worked for me:

```
<screen
    android:screenDensity="420"
    android:screenSize="normal" />

<screen
    android:screenDensity="560"
    android:screenSize="normal" />
```

The 2nd one I added for **Galaxy Note5**, for which one user reported not seeing the app.

(variants of Note5 have 420dpi and 560dpi density)

Now **S8 +** is showing 'Supported' as well:

[image]

Putting the first one alone for S8 + didn't work.

**P.S.** Also added Ali Ahsan's patch, but couldn't test for it's effect alone.

Comment: @Dan did you try this?

Comment: Well, now it's showing that both S8/S8+ are supported but I'll have wait and see if people are actually able to install the app on either phone since I don't own one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to support the large aspect ratio, you need to do this:

In the  tag of your app manifest, add the following meta-data:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
```

By doing so, you tell the android system that this app is designed to support maximum aspect ratio of 18.5:9 (approx. and that by the way is the aspect ratio of S8, S8+).

Comment: I added that and still no change.